# Explanation of Split() Method

Tags: c#

I am implementing fileupload/downloading from SQL Server. Code is working all fine.

I came across this code - can someone please explain what this line is doing?

```
string[] strPath = strFile.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\"));
```

I know it's splitting a string (`strFile`) ... and I think the delimiter is '`\`'. But why is a string array `string[] strPath` declared? And why is `(Convert.ToChar())` used ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Convert.ToChar(@"\")` could be `'\\'` as well. The first slash is to escape the second. `@'\'` does not work for chars. And `'\'` escapes the second quote, not closing the char definition. `Convert.ToChar(@"\")` is a verbose way of writing whats necessary.
An array of `string[]` is declared because if you split a string with a delimiter it can return multiple strings, if the delimter was found. Each splitted piece is a seperate string.

Comment: Was just about to write a answere, I am so slow! Well written!

Comment: Same as butterbox, deleted my answer when I saw yours, Only thing I was going to add is if its to create a path, then Path.Combine should be used

Comment: @Mike de Klerk , So you mean array `string[] strPath` is created to hold all the substrings resulted when delimiter '/' is found? ... If so, that means we get an array of strings (if more than 1 string is resulted) ? So in this case `strPath` holds the subStrings in its indexes?

Comment: @RehanMehdi Yes totally! `String[] Pieces = "split|me|in|4".Split('|');` would result in a `String` array with 4 values/indices. Where `Pieces[0]` is 'split' and `Pieces[3]` is '4'

Comment: @Sayse , Thanks for replying. It is to hold the path of the file when the file is browsed by the user as input. Thanks

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Thank you so much Sir. Hats off to you. Stay blessed.

Answer (score 2):

@Rehan Mehdi here string array declare because when you split a string it means u making number of part of that string, to store different-2 part of string u need different-2 space which string array provide.And Convert.ToChar() means u try to convert parameter this as char.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the result of strFile.Split() is a array of string that is more than once. The `(Convert.ToChar())` is used because there is no overload accepting (only) a string but there are for param array of char. Look at MSDN link at ssilas777's answer.

Comment: You could instead add the link to your own answer instead if referring to another answer.

Comment: @Default I'm on hurry, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) For String.Split

`Split` method returns a string array that contains the substrings, so `string` array is declared and `Split` method is expecting `params char[]` as parameter(seperator) , so `Convert.ToChar(@"\")`
is used.

In this case '\' as separator should also works.

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(String)` is not returning an array of chars: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y.aspx

Comment: a little correction, `Split` method expects `params char[]`, so a single `char` can be passed

Comment: @MikedeKlerk I haven't mentioned Convert to char(string) returns array of char. What made you think so.

Comment: @GuruStron, Yes Indeed, that's an typo.